# Точки пересечения двух GraphicsPath

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть два GraphicsPath (линия и дуга):

```
GraphicsPath graphicsPathLine = new GraphicsPath()
graphicsPathLine.AddLine(line.StartPoint, line.EndPoint)

GraphicsPath _ArcPath = new GraphicsPath();
_ArcPath.AddArc(_RestrictRectangle, _StartAngle, _SweepAngle);
```

Есть ли возможность найти их точку (точки) пересечения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно, можно.

Нужно записать уравнение эллипса для дуги (оно определяется ограничивающи прямоугольником), подставить в него зависимость Y/X для линии, решить уравнение, и проверить, входят ли точки решения (их может быть 0,1,2) в диапазон углов, ограничивающих дугу, и, если линия на самом деле отрезок - в пределы отрезка.